# xslt contains function to test for a string

Tags: xml, xslt

**[UPDATE] : I was not able to solve the below problem and had to change the if condition completely to suite my needs. Since the XSLT code was being written inside a web application which had a lot of restriction such as I was not able to get the input XML file or output XSLT file etc which prevented healthy solutions and suggestions from other users.**

**[Moderator] : Let me know what i could do to this question in SO so that it serves best for everyone.**

I am trying to test for a particular string using XSLT contains function (which is not working). Below are my test results with observation

I am getting the text which i need to test via this code.

```
<xsl:template name="TESTDATA_here">
  <xsl:call-template name="TESTDATA_here">
        <xsl:with-param name="TESTDATA_here" select="nodeName/TESTDATA_here"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

With the above code, i get ##TESTDATE_here## as a variable which when executed prints the actual text. So far works fine.
I am then assigning the output to a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="testdata_here">##TESTDATA_here##</xsl:variable>
```

I have also tried using

```
<xsl:variable name="testdata_here" select="##TESTDATA_here##" />
```

But i guess the above method is not correct as it considers ##TESTDATA_here## as a string and not as a variable.

Now i want to check for contains(), so I have tried below code,

```
<xsl:if test="contains($testdata_here, 'T')">
This does not work :(
</xsl:if>
```

Can anyone point what is wrong with the code?

Comment: This is very confusing. Why don't you start at the beginning (where is this "particular string" coming from), move to the middle (what do you want to know about this string) and conclude with the end (what do you want to happen as a result in each case).

Comment: Hey @michael.hor257k, I am working inside a web app which uses xslt to get data from data views. The first piece of code works fine and i get the required text in my variable ##TESTDTA_here##. However the problem is when i try to assign it to my xsl variable so i can use it inside the contains().

Comment: Well, the problem **here** is that I have no idea what your question is...

Comment: Sorry if the question is confusing/not written well. My problem is that i am not able to execute my xsl if condition in which i am trying to use contains(). I anticipate that the variable $testdata_here is not being written/created correctly, so i was looking for any help in xsl:variable function. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The literal string should be in single quotes, like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="testdata_here" select="'##TESTDATA_here##'" />
```

Comment: Can you post your input XML, XSLT used, and expected output XML?

Comment: I don't have input xml, as i am writing my xslt code within a paid web application. What i want is to be able to execute my xslt if condition <xsl:if test="contains($testdata_here, 'T')">//text</xsl:if>

Comment: Could you post your whole XSLT file used, at least?

Comment: Hi, The above code is pretty much everything in that xslt file. The web application lets me create a dynamic file, and i can write my code in there, I just have to check "XSLT" as one of the option and rest all is taken care of. If you see my first code snippet, (first block) it works fine. Not sure, what is wrong with the XSLT if condition. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @noobcode "*I don't have input xml*" I would suggest you use an *identity transform template* on your input and capture the result. That is your input XML and it can be very valuable in analyzing what's happening (and what's not). Without this, you are working in the dark.